# Change class of submenu-item of two level menu wordpress by wordpress functions only

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress

I have integrated a html template into wordpress theme. But, menu is trouble for me. I have menu bar in header part. It has also submenu. I have applied css classes to 1st level menu items. But, on submenu items I am not able to add classes through wordpress functions. Is there any wordpress functions to do so?

Below, is the code for menubar which is coded by wordpress function in `header.php`.

```
<?php
wp_nav_menu(
    array(
        'theme_location' => 'new-menu',
        'container_class' => 'ske-menu',
        'container_id' => 'skenav',
        'items_wrap' => '<ul id="menu-main" class="menu sf-js-enabled sf-arrows">%3$s</ul>'
    )
);
?>
```

I have menu like below image and I am unable to add classes to submenu items.

[image]

That means on hover of COMPANY, I am not getting "About Us", "Executive Team" (etc) submenus.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: If you just want to style those items, you can use css selectors for that.

Comment: I have ready css classes for that menu. But when I have integrated that html template to wordpress theme, I am just unable to add submenu classes to menu with wordpress function. Remember I don`t want to use WORDPRESS`s class. I want to use my(HTML-Template`s) classes to make sub-menu working.